# Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set (On Oracle DB)

Tags: oracle, hibernate, oracle12c

I already read other posts about this problem, but mine is not a Hibernate problem, is a connection problem.

I installed **Oracle database 12 c** on a new machine, but I can't connect my web application to it. I get this error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to 
DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
```

And I'm sure that this problem is just about the connection. The application perfectly works if I try to connect to a MySQL database.

This is my **tnsnamesora** file

```
LISTENER_ORCL =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))


ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )
```

These are my connection data:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/orcl
spring.datasource.username=DB_EXAMPLE
spring.datasource.password=Frema16242 //this is correct
spring.datasource.database-driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
hibernate.c3p0.preferred_test_query=SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
```

These are the Oracle services running on my pc.

[image]

Of course I'm able to connect to my schema using Toad .

Can you spot what is my error?

Answer (score 0):

I think i had same problem like you. I tried to set connection using datasource. I used sessionFactory with constructor datasource argument. I solved it when i created properties object and i put hibernate.dialect property to it. Next i set this properties on my sessionFactory object.

Comment: The problem was the driver. I changed from ojdbc14.jar to ojdbc6.jar and it started working. I face this problem only when running the app under Tomcat. Under weblogic I'm able to connect to the database both using ojdbc14 and ojdbc6.